# How do I point a specific page of my website to a Tumblr blog?

Tags: redirect, dns, tumblr

I know Tumblr makes it very easy to point your TumblrBlog to a specific subdomain by changing the "CNAME" or "A" record in DNS. I wanted to know how can I point the TumblrBlog to website.com/blog rather than the subdomain blog.website.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply prefer **website.com/blog** over **blog.website.com**, you could set up the former url with a redirect to **blog.website.com**. That has the added benefit of allowing people to access the site two different ways.

However, if the problem is that you can't change your DNS settings, you could use an iframe. That probably isn't a very good idea though, because it messes with the browser's back and forward buttons and doesn't display the updated url when you navigate within the frame.

Another non-DNS solution, if you have some kind of scripting available, is to use Tumblr's API to recreate your blog in your own page.

Your options are really dependent on your situation, which you haven't told us much about.